# open REST cypher transaction

Tags: rest, groovy, neo4j

Trying to write a script to open a transaction in groovy.  Currently have:

```
def static transaction(statement, params,success, error)
{
    def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://localhost:7474' )
    http.request( POST, JSON ) {
        uri.path = '/db/data/transaction'
        headers.'X-Stream' = 'true'
        requestContentType = JSON
        body =  [ statements : statement , params : params ?: [:] ]

        // uri.query = [ param : 'value' ]

        response.success = { resp, json ->
            if (success) success(json)
            else {
                println "Status ${resp.statusLine} Columns ${json.columns}\nData: ${json.data}"
            }
        }

        response.failure = { resp, message ->
            def result=[status:resp.statusLine.statusCode,statusText:resp.statusLine.reasonPhrase]
            result.headers = resp.headers.collect { h -> [ (h.name) : h.value ] }
            result.message = message
            if (error) {
                error(result)
            } else {
                println "Status: ${result.status} : ${result.statusText} "
                println 'Headers: ${result.headers}'
                println 'Message: ${result.message}'
            }
        }
    }
}
transaction("start n=node(*) return n",[id:56981],{ println "Success: ${it}" },{ println "Error: ${it}" })
```

However I am getting the following error in the response:

```
Success: [commit:http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/4/commit, results:[], errors:[[code:40001, status:INVALID_REQUEST_FORMAT, message:Unable to deserialize request. Expected [START_OBJECT, FIELD_NAME, START_ARRAY], found [START_OBJECT, FIELD_NAME, VALUE_STRING].]]]
```

Thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Which milestone are you using?

Comment: Currently using 2.0.0-M5

Comment: For debugging it might be useful to put a proxy in between your application and Neo4j, e.g. http://www.charlesproxy.com/ is useful. This way you can inspect exactly what's going over the wire.

Comment: Thanks Stefan!  I downloaded it but all it is seeing is the fetch requests from Neo.  No http requests that I am hitting it with.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out https://gist.github.com/7053223. Basically you did not build the json structure correctly. According to http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html a json map containing `statements` key is sent. Inside there's an array of maps containing a `statement` and `parameters` key. Compare l.15 vs l.16-18 to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem with php, `statements` must contain array of `statement`:

```
[
    statements => [
        statemant
    ],
    resultDataContents => [
        'row',
        'graph',
    ],
    'includeStats' => true,
]
```